# Vector multiplication sign

Tags: vectors

In the link below there is a short excerpt from the text I'm using:

[image]

I am stuck for a while on how he got that fraction result, after the dot product. I am multiplying the cross product part by $ \vec C = C_x \hat i + C_y \hat j $ and get the signs changed on both the denominator and numerator.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you change signs on both numerator and denominator of a fraction, how does that affect the value of the fraction?

Comment: Fantastic answer, David. Thanks

Comment: $\frac{a-b}{c-d}=\frac{b-a}{d-c}$